# how to deal with dollar sign in column name in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame called counts, and one column name is called merged$year. When I apply the codes

```
counts %>% 
  group_by(counts$merged$year) %>% 
 mutate(C= sum(V1))
```

to this data frame, it always shows

```
 Error: Unsupported type NILSXP for column "counts$merged$year"
```

I tried to change the name for the column, so the codes became

```
counts %>% 
  group_by(counts$merged1gwmd, counts$merged1year) %>% 
  mutate(C= sum(V1))
```

but I still got error:

```
 Error: invalid subscript type 'double'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use backticks to select those columns, but it is not recommended to have these kind of column names.

```
counts %>% 
     group_by(`merged$year`) %>% 
     mutate(C= sum(V1))
#  `merged$year`         V1          C
#          <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#1          2001  0.2832134 -1.8231106
#2          2001 -2.1063239 -1.8231106
#3          2002 -1.3826456 -0.2244838
#4          2002  1.1581617 -0.2244838
```

NOTE: `counts$` is not needed as we are passing only the column name

and for the second case, it is

```
names(counts)[1:2] <- c("merged1year", "merged1gwmd")
counts %>% 
     group_by(merged1gwmd, merged1year) %>% 
     mutate(C= sum(V1))
#  merged1year merged1gwmd         V1            C
#        <dbl>      <fctr>      <dbl>        <dbl>
#1        2001           A  0.9365008  1.344889500
#2        2001           A  0.4083887  1.344889500
#3        2002           B -0.4675696 -0.001339325
#4        2002           B  0.4662303 -0.001339325
```

#### data

```
counts <- data.frame(`merged$year` = c(2001, 2001, 2002, 2002),
                     `merged$gwmd` = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 2),
                           V1 = rnorm(4), check.names = FALSE)
```